# How to crop resulting PDF to the size of the SVG?

Tags: latex3, svg

I have a latex file containing the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[inkscapearea=page]{svg}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \includesvg[scale=1.0]{idea.svg}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I compile this with `latexmk -pdflatex --shell-escape idea.tex`. The resulting PDF doesn't crop the page based on the SVG extents. How can I get a PDF which is cropped based on the included svg drawing extents?

## My workflow

As per @AlexG's comment here is a clarification of my workflow.

1. Compile an SVG file to PDF using LaTeX, only because LaTeX will render the math in the Text boxes of the SVG file. Call this `image.pdf`
2. Include the resulting pdf into a markdown document  like this `![test](image.pdf`
3. Generate a PDF from the markdown document using `pandoc test.md -o test.pdf`

Comment: Try the `standalone` document class if you want the output to be cropped to the visible page content.

Comment: I actually want to process the LaTeX math inside my SVG with LaTeX and then include it as an image in my markdown document using Pandoc. So I'm afraid using `standalone` won't do in this case. Please see https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/265

Comment: Your workflow is not clear to me. It seems you want SVG with TeX-formatted math content that is to be included later in a markdown document, right? SVG output can be produced with tools present in TeX installations: `latex` and `dvisvgm`.

Comment: "It seems you want SVG with TeX-formatted math content that is to be included later in a markdown document, right?" -->

That's exactly correct. Once they are included in the markdown document I would run a `pandoc test.md -o test.pdf` which would trigger a second run of the LaTeX compiler, only now including the SVGs as embedded images. Does that make the workflow clearer to you?

Comment: `latex input` to generate `input.dvi`. Then, `dvisvgm --zoom=-1 --exact --font-format=woff2 input` to convert `input.dvi` to `input.svg`.

Comment: @AlexG sorry, but that doesn't seem to work. All the graphic elements disappear in the result of that `dvisvgm` call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144405/discussion-between-alexg-and-user32882).

Comment: Problem was not solved in the chat.